# Restrict who can approve pull request

Tags: azure-devops

I'm just wondering if there is anyway to restrict who can approve pull requests, or who can be included in on a pull request.

I know you can provide a list of reviewees from a group, or setup auto reviewers... but specifically say people in role x, cannot hit approve or deny on a pull request.

Comment: Did you look at the security settings on the branch?

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question,  If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT The need seems to be how to do you setup up a group that cannot approve PRs. Is there a way to create a VSTS group of users that is not allowed to approve PRs?

Comment: @GDF, AFAIK, there is no such a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> but specifically say people in role x, cannot hit approve or deny on a pull request.

The most direct or best way to restrict approval requests is to add auto reviewers or groups.

If you want to assign this permission to the people **in role X** instead of adding reviewers or groups, I am afraid Azure devops does not provide a feature to meet this requirement at this moment.

Besides, if anyone in role x but not in the reviewers, the, he approve or rejects PR is not decisive for the final PR completion, it is like a comment:

[image]

So, suppose we have such a function, but it is still limited to reviewers.

Hope this helps.